# How to get the value of dynamically created dropdown using javascript? And get all values

Tags: javascript, html, dropdownlistfor

1. Here the drop down list is created dynamically.
2. We are able to get the first value but rest of the value are displayed same as first value.
3. And we need to concatenate all the values.
4. When we change the number of conditions it's getting added with the existing one.

Can anyone help me on these? Note: need solution only in JavaScript.

```js
    var counter = 1;
    var str="";
    var con="";

    function addInput(divName) {
        var count=document.getElementById("ConditionId").value;
         for(i=1;i<=count;i++)
         {
              var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
              newdiv.innerHTML = "Condition " + (counter + 0) + " <br><input list='alert' onchange='GetCondition();' id='value'>";
              document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
              counter++;                  
         }                   
    }

    function GetCondition() 
    {           
        str = document.getElementById("value").value;
        con=con.concat(str);
        alert(con);
    }
```

```html
<html>
        <head>
            <title>Formatter</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        </head>
        <body>
            <form>
            <div id="dynamicInput">                  
                Number of Condition:<input type="number" id="ConditionId" onchange="addInput('dynamicInput');">
                
                <br/>
               
                <datalist id='alert'>
                <option>Demo 1</option>
                <option>Demo 2</option>
                <option>Demo 3</option>
                <option>Demo 4</option>
                <option>Demo 5</option>
                <option>Demo 6</option>
                </datalist>
         </div>             
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here i'm getting only the first value right, and other value are same as first value.Need it to change as per the selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can get specific value, if you will know which element you should select.

First of all, in your js function `addInput` you generating a bunch of inputs with same id. This is bad. Try something like this: ... `id='value' + i`

Second, I think you should add different identificators to all your options. With specific id you can get all info you want.

OR you can get array of `option` elements. but then you have to know index of each `option`

Comment: and with all that, maybe you should use some event listeners to ask specific option about its value. i dont know... you'll figure something out)

Comment: Also try W3Shools.com
it helped me a lot with all this js/html/jquery/css stuff

Comment: I'm already using W3schools.com for my reference. But could you be more specific where i'm going wrong in the code. so that i can get the desired output.